# Implementing B=f(A), with B and A arrays and B already defined

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Suppose I have an array `B` that has been already defined and used somewhere in a C++ code. Now, suppose that I have another array `A` that has been defined and initialized. I want to create a function `f` that transforms `A` (for example, an FFT) and I want that the result of the transformation is assigned to `B` (of course, following the transformation of `A`, `B` will change its values). I want to do all that by keeping the syntax

```
B=f(A);
```

namely, without passing the address of `B` as an argument to `f`. Is it possible:

1. without the creation of temporaries?
2. with the creation of temporaries, but without memory leaks?

Thank you.

**EDIT: SUMMARY OF THE SOLUTIONS PROVIDED IN THE ANSWERS BELOW**

Thanks to RiaD, James Kanze, Shahbaz and Razispio for their answers.

What I'm asking requires `A` and `B` to be objects of an array class in order to gain efficiency and effectiveness. Also, in a "standard" implementation, e.g., with an array class equipped with a copy constructor, a syntax like `B=f(A);` would require the creation of temporaries. It should be however mentioned that temporaries are not necessarily a limitation, since many compilers would be able to elide the extra temporaries. Opposite to this, a syntax like `f(A,B);` would avoid temporaries. The solution using *expression templates* enables the syntax `B=f(A);` while internally using `f(A,B);`, making the use of temporaries negligible. An efficient alternative solution would be using move assignment operators, see for example

[Move semantics and rvalue references in C++11](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html)

For details, see the answers kindly provided below.

Comment: "The best solution is using expression templates": this depends on many issues. For complex mathematical libraries, particularly with operators (e.g. `Matrix::operator+`), expression templates (or an expression inheritance hierarchy) is probably justified, both for reasons of runtime _and_ memory use.  In most other cases, however, it results in an excessively complicated solution for little real benefit.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that. Of course, "best" depends on the "metrics" you use to evaluate the "goodness" of a solution, I agree. For my purpose, that solution would be the "best". I have rephrased the last sentence saying that "The solution using expression templates enables the syntax `B=f(A);` while internally using `f(A,B);`, making the use of temporaries negligible." What do you think about?

Comment: That when I hear the term "expression templates", I generally imagine a lot more.  Things like `operator+` returning a proxy type which doesn't do any of the arithmetic until you ask for a specific value, for example.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thanks. Perhaps you are right. Using move semantics could be easier and much efficient as well, see [Move semantics and rvalue references in C++11](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way it to use `std::vector` or `std::array`

example:

```
vector<int> f(const vector<int>& a) {
   return a;
}

b = f(a);
```

Actually, you don't have to use one of this classes to store, you may use your own class, that have `operator =`

```
YourClass& operator = (const vector<int>&/* there will be returned value of f, it may be std::array, std::vector or your own class.*/ v) {
    //fill it here.
    return *this;
}
```

You may also provide move constructor for it to avoid unnecessary copying.

for example

```
class Array {
    int* data;   
    YourClass& operator = (YourClass&& v) {
        swap(v.data, data);
    }
}

YourClass f(const YourClass& a) {
   //
}

Array a,b;
b = f(a);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I forgot mentioning that I'm using my own array class, so I would like to avoid using `std::vector` or `std::array`. Would it be possible to elaborate more on your answer for a generic `int` array? Also, in your suggested solution I have the feeling that `a` is transformed in `f`, but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: @JackOLantern: You will need to have `f()` return a type that is compatible with `B` provided `B` has a copy constructor or assignment operator defined.  You are executing `B.operator=(f(a))`.

Comment: It depends what your array class is. It will not work with `int a[100]`, but maybe will work with your class(you could show it). `a` will not be transformed because it's passed as _const reference_

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you for your comment. Actually, my operators `A` and `B` are already objects of an array class of my own. I was omitting that in the post to simplify the question. So, you are basically suggesting to implement a copy constructor for my array class. In the function `f`, I will then create a temporary object and `return` its value. The value of the temporary will then be assigned to `B` by the copy constructor. Am I right? Is your comment related to the second part of Shahbaz answer? Thanks.

Comment: @RiaD I will show my array class in a post edit. But, if you `return a`, does it mean that `a` should be changed? Should you `return` a temporary?

Comment: @JackOLantern Note that this solution is the simplest, but does allocate a temporary (in that the memory of `b` is not reused). If you do implement the copy constructor, and you have access to move constructors, don't forget to implement that too, it will make the move much more efficient (although not remove the copy).

Comment: JackOLanern I return `a` jut as an example. Anyway temporary will be returned

Comment: @RiaD In your edited post, should it be `YourClass& operator = (const YourClass<int>& v)` insteas of `YourClass& operator = (const vector<int>& v)`? Is your post the implementation of a copy constructor? Thanks,

Comment: no, I showed how you may `return std::vector` and then put in your class

Answer (score 1):

Since `f` doesn't have any references to `B`, it has no way but work on a local array. You would therefore then have to copy the values to `B`. So in the current form, no there is no way. However, if you make `f` inline, the optimizer may just help you with that<sup>1</sup>, but that wouldn't be a good idea for an FFT for example.

With temporary values but no memory leak, you can simply wrap the array in a class (or use `vector` which already does that) and return that. Note that non-dynamic-array copy itself doesn't produce memory leaks, it's just not possible in C++ to write `some_array = another_array`.

If you have the option for a redesign, best way would be to call `f(A, B)` for maximum performance,

---

<sup>1</sup> If the compiler is smart enough, it would recognize that a local array in `f` is going to be copied over to `B`, and in the inline version of `f` it could use `B` itself since it has access to it.

Comment: Except that the compiler is allowed to elide the extra temporaries, and today, practically all compilers do.

Comment: @Shahbaz Thank you for your answer. I'm mainly interested to FFTs, but could you please expand your point on function inlining? The second part of your answer seems to be related to implementation of copy constructors, as suggested by Thomas Matthews, isn't it? From your answer, I would then conclude that, the syntax `B=f(A);` requires a temporary. It will not lead to memory leaks, since the temporary will be removed from the stack when the function returns. On the other side, the syntax `f(A,B);` does not require a temporary and is then more efficient. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @JackOLantern, ok I will explain the inline part a bit more. In the meantime, yes your understanding is correct.

Comment: @JamesKanze, in case of `vector` (aka dynamic memories), that is true, but certainly not for stack memory. If you have B of type `struct { int array[100]; };`, there is no way for the compiler to avoid the copy simply because there is some memory in the stack frame of `f` that needs to be copied to the stack frame of the caller (where `B` is).

Comment: @Shahbaz Most compilers _do_ elide the extra copy in such cases.  There's no rule which was that any particular variable has to be in the current stack frame, where it will disappear when the function returns; if you return a local variable, most, if not all compilers will simply place the local variable where ever they put return values.  Similarly, at the call site, most compilers will elide the returned temporary and the returned value.

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible (or very nearly, `f(a)`), if you are willing to use a custom type for `b`. The idea is that you already have `b`, hence you want to semantically pass it as an argument to `f`. For example, we can overload the assignment operator for that:

First, define an expression concept (here represented as an abstract class, but we don't really want to use virtual dispatch). This encapsulates a computation, that can `Evaluate` and returns the result in the `target`.

```
template<typename T>
class Expression
{
public:
    virtual void Evaluate(T& target) const = 0;
}
```

Now define your array class, that can be assigned from an `Expression` class. When an expression is assigned, it is evaluated.

```
template<typename T>
class Array
{
   T* ptr;
public:
   template<typename Expression>
   const Array<T> operator =(Expression const & expression)
   {
      expression.Evaluate(ptr);
   }
}
```

Now, define your function `f` to return an expression, that when evaluated, returns `f(a)`.

```
class MyExpression
{
    float* a;
public:
    MyExpression(float* a) : a(a) {}
    void Evaluate(float* target)
    {
        f(a, b);
    }
}

MyExpression<float> f(float* a) 
{ 
    return MyExpression(a);
}
```

Which you can then call as follows

```
Array b;
b = f(a);
```

This does create a temporary (on the stack), but it could be inlined away. For example, suppose we have the call

```
b = f(a);
```

this is equivalent to

```
b.operator = (f (a));
```

inlining the call to `operator =`, we get

```
(f(a)).Evaluate(b);
```

now, we can also inline the call to `f`, giving

```
(MyExpression(f)).Evaluate(b);
```

now, the compiler can just notice that this is exactly the same as doing

```
f(a, b);
```

and do that straight away. Hence, no need to create the temporary `MyExpression`, though its cost is negligible in the first place (it's a stack allocation of `sizeof(Array)`)

Note that this type of strategy is used by the matrix library [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) to avoid temporaries for example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually, my array class is already based on expression templates. What you suggest seems to be an alternative way to implement copy constructors, isn't it? From the last part of your answer, inlining would hint the compiler to "internally" avoid temporaries? Of course, the last question is: how eigen uses this solution to avoid temporaries? :-)

Comment: @JackOLantern we don't really avoid temporaries per say, but there is no heap allocation. There is a temporary of type `Expression` created, but on the stack, and it only contains the arguments anyway, so there is no inefficiency there.

Concerning eigen, they use it mainly to eliminate temporaries in composite expressions. For example, writing `a = b + c + d` usually incurs the creation of a temporary `c + d`, which is then added to `b + (c + d)`. However, eigen analyzes the expression and rewrites it too something equivalent to `AddThree(b, c, d, a)`, with no temporaries created.

Comment: Thanks. When I asked about eigen, I though it was using expression templates to avoid temporaries in copies. Yes, I'm also implementing expression templates to avoid temporaries in expressions like `a = b + c + d`. From your solution, it seems that you can use the syntax `f(a,b)` which could be more efficient than `b=f(a)` (see the Shahbaz thread). It would be interesting to compare such a solution with the move construction solution of RiaD and James Kanze. What do you think about?

Comment: You could also inline copies. In fact, with any modern compiler, the two syntaxes `b = f(a)` and `f(a, b)` are equivalent. I'll elaborate my answer.

Comment: @Razispio `b = f(a)` and `f(a, b)` have very different semantics, and no compiler will ever replace one with the other.  The programmer can do so, but only because he knows that the difference in semantics is irrelevant.  (I suppose that the compiler could figure this out in a few special cases, but it is very, difficult.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I meant in the implementation above, of course. And yes any modern compiler should be able to do the inlining I've described above, as everything is known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

First, it depends on what you mean by array.  With the usual C++
meaning (`std::vector`), there will never be any problem with
memory leaks; with the usual C meaning (`T[]`), `B = f( A )` is
an illegal.  If you define your own array type, then it should
behave more or less like `std::vector` in this respect.

With regards to extra temporaries: `f` should take its argument
as a const reference, so that there will be no copying to pass
the argument.  As for the return value, there is formally a
copy, but the compiler is allowed to alide it, and most do, at
least some of the time.  In an assignment statement, the actual
data of the array *will* probably be copied in the assignment
itself.

In C++11, you can provide a move constructor and a move
assignment operator, and (probably) reduce the chances of a copy
even more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, copying temporaries seems not to be anymore a concern (of course, depending on temporaries). I'm using Visual Studio 2010, which I know supports some of the features of C++11. Does it supports also move constructors and move assignment operators? Could you please introduce me to those topics with some references? Thanks.

Comment: As usual, the answer is: it depends.  Globally, it matters a lot less than it used to---I'm currently working on a very performance critical application, and we return containers all over the place.  But there will be times...  My answer is to use the natural syntax _until_ the profiler says that it is a problem.  At which point, you can overload `f` with `void f( B& dest, A const& src )`, implement the original version (returning `B`) in terms of this, and use this more awkward version where the profiler says you must.