# Implementing the B=f(A) syntax by move assignment

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, move

I have implemented a Matrix class with a move assignment as

```
template <typename OutType>
class Matrix
{
    public:
        int Rows_;                      // number of Rows
        int Columns_;                   // number of Columns
        OutType *data_;                 // row Major order allocation

    // STUFF

        Matrix<OutType> & operator=(Matrix<float>&& other) {
            swap(other);
            return *this;
        }

        void swap(Matrix<float>& other) {
            int t_Rows_ = Rows_;        Rows_ = other.Rows_;        other.Rows_ = t_Rows_;
            int t_Columns_ = Columns_;  Columns_ = other.Columns_;  other.Columns_ = t_Columns_;
            float* t_ptr = data_;
            data_ = other.data_;
            other.data_ = t_ptr; }      
}
```

in order to implement the `B=f(A);` syntax, as suggested in

[C++: Implementing B=f(A), with B and A arrays and B already defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254797/c-implementing-b-fa-with-b-and-a-arrays-and-b-already-defined)

As possible function, I'm considering the FFT, implemented as

```
Matrix<float> FFT(const Matrix<float> &in)
{
    Matrix<float> out(in.GetRows(),in.GetColumns());

    // STUFF

    return out;
}
```

Is there any room for further efficiency improvements? Is there any further trick to improve, for example, the move assignment or the `swap` function?

**EDIT: NEW SOLUTION FOLLOWING KONRAD RUDOLPH'S COMMENT**

```
        Matrix & operator=(Matrix&& other) {
            std::swap(Rows_, other.Rows_);
            std::swap(Columns_, other.Columns_);
            std::swap(data_, other.data_); 
            std::cout << "move assigned \n";
            return *this;
        }
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you Konrad, but why do you say that `B=f(A);` will never call `operator(Matrix&&)`? I have verified that the execution passes through that piece of code by printing an `hello` text. Removing the template arguments from `operator=` and `swap` arguments are good ideas. Thanks.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Its not trying to bind `A`; its binding the return value of `f(A)` to the rvalue reference.

Comment: @Chris Ah of course. …

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks Chris. That is exactly the point. I have edited my post according to Konrad's comment. When I call `B=f(A);` then the code prints the `move assigned` string I have added to the move assignment.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are bothering to implement your own Matrix class... perhaps as an academic exercise? If you actually need performance, I recommend you use something off-the-shelf like the Eigen 3 library (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page ) Their documentation also explains some of the very advanced optimizations they do to get kick-ass performance. Cheers.

Comment: @SchighSchagh Thanks for your comment. Actually, my aim is to write a library to run on the GPU by CUDA programming, for which something like eigen does not exist (or, at least, I'm not aware of). Therefore, I need to have everything under control. Of course, I could try to steal some clever solutions from eigen for my own case.

Comment: some CUDA linear algebra/math libraries: https://developer.nvidia.com/technologies/Libraries In particular, CUBLAS comes with CUDA... I think the API is C-style, so I can see why you might want to encapsulate it in OOP style interface.

Comment: @SchighSchagh :-) The same holds true for the CUFFT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend implementing move-assignment and move-construction for your class:

```
Matrix( Matrix<OutType> &&that ) noexcept
    : Rows_(that.Rows_)
    , Cols_(that.Cols_)
    , data_(that.data_)
{
    that.Rows_ = that.Cols_ = 0;
    that.data_ = nullptr;
}
Matrix<OutType> &operator=( Matrix<OutType> &&that ) noexcept {
     using std::swap;
     swap( Rows_, that.Rows_ );
     swap( Cols_, that.Cols_ );
     swap( data_, that.data_ );
     return *this;
}
```

If you implement move operations (construction and assignment) like this, `std::swap` should work great for your code, and you don't need to provide your own.  If you do want to provide your own implementation of `swap`, I recommend providing it as a two-argument `friend` function so that it can be found through Argument Dependent Look-up.  I also recommend calling `swap` (and all other functions) without namespace qualifications, as shown above, so that ADL is not suppressed (unless, for some reason, you really need to specify exactly which function is called, and an overload customized for the specific type would be wrong).  ADL is especially valuable when dealing with templated code.  If you call `std::swap` with the `std::` qualifier, you significantly reduce the opportunity for user-defined types to provide a more efficient swap implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer. Following Konrad Rudolph's comment, I would say that we could remove the template arguments from your solution, right? Also, are you sure about the `noexcept` syntax? When using it, for example, for the `operator=`, the compiler complains and says `expected a ";"` at the first line of that operator. Is this feature compatible with Visual Studio 2010? Is it "really" needed? Thank you very much.

Comment: @JackOLantern: WRT including the template parameter list, I usually include it, but I've sometimes forgotten it and the compiler hasn't complained, so it's probably a style thing.

Comment: @JackOLantern: WRT the `noexcept`, I believe that's the right syntax and GCC accepts it, but I can't speak for Visual Studio (since I develop on Linux and Microsoft hasn't ported to my platform yet ;-) ).  It is not "necessary" in the sense that you can have move operations that don't use it, but in many cases if it's not there, the standard library will opt to copy instead of move.  For example, without it, you may need to provide your own `friend` overload of `swap()` because `std::swap` won't use a throwing move on a copyable type.  (You might try using `throw()` instead for Visual Studio.)

Comment: @JackOLantern: I just did a quick Google search and found that Visual Studio 2012 doesn't seem to support the `noexcept` syntax.  I would recommend putting `throw()` in place of `noexcept` as a workaround.  That syntax is deprecated in C++11, but it is equivalent to `noexcept` and should give you more portable code while Visual Studio catches up.

Comment: Thanks. I have successfully used `throw()` under Visual Studio 2010.