# Implementing the [B,C]=f(A) syntax (function f acting on an array with two or more output arrays)

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have a question which is an extension of other two questions I have recently posted:

[Implementing B=f(A), with B and A arrays and B already defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254797/implementing-b-fa-with-b-and-a-arrays-and-b-already-defined)

and

[Implementing the B=f(A) syntax by move assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287644/implementing-the-b-fa-syntax-by-move-assignment)

Suppose I have an array `A`. I want to create a function `f` that acts on `A` and returns two other arrays `B` and `C`, by enabling the following Matlab-like syntax

```
[B,C]=f(A);
```

Is it possible in C++?

**SOLUTION FOLLOWING LEEMES' ANSWER**

```
#include <tuple>
using std::tie;

std::tuple<TypeOfB,TypeOfC> f(const Matrix<T1>&a,const Matrix<T2>&a) {

    // Instruction declaring and defining B_temp and C_temp

    return std::make_tuple(B_temp,C_temp); }

int main( int argc, char** argv) 
{

    // Instruction declaring A, B and C

    tie(B,C)=f(A);

    // STUFF

    return 0;

 }
```

Everything works also when changing `std::tuple` and `make_tuple` to `std::pair` and `std::make_pair` for this particular case (only two outputs).

Comment: In C++, this type of operation would be done using containers.  f(x) would return a container reference that is declared to contain two arrays.  However, as this is C++, you should be using containers in place of the arrays themselves.

Comment: Note that *raw* arrays should only be used in *some* cases. Try to use higher level containers, such as `std::vector` (dynamic size) or `std::array` (constant size, since C++11).

Comment: @leemes I'm using my own array class, since I'm dealing with template metaprogramming to gain efficiency.

Comment: @JackOLantern: The authors of `std::array` may use tricks that you may not, because `std::array` is part of the implementation. Therefore, don't assume your version is more efficient, even if it is as good as you can make it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, if you want to return multiple values, you have to do some little work-around, since C++ doesn't allow this out of the box.

The first option is to return a [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) containing both values. Then you can use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) in a return statement if you have C++11 available, like this:

```
std::tie(B, C) = f(A);
```

(Note: C++11 also has [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple) for more than two values.)

Or you can pass the two target variables by reference, but then the function call becomes something like this (works without C++11):

```
f(A, B, C);
```

To make the function call look more "verbose" (some people don't like that you can't tell that `f` changes `B` and `C` from looking at this single line of code) you can also use pointers instead of references. Then the function call would look like this:

```
f(A, &B, &C);
```

Another option is to use a simple "container" for your multiple return values. This is useful in particular if a simple pair or tuple don't give the values a particular meaning. The best option is to use this consistently in the code which calls `f` (don't use separate arrays `B` and `C`). Use this only if it fits nicely into the rest of your code design.

```
struct TwoArrays {
    int B[100];
    int C[100];
};

TwoArrays result = f(A);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your solutions using pair(tuple)/tie and the container are very promising. I do not like the `f(A,B,C);` syntax, as it is very different from that offered by Matlab. From your answer, I understand that the answer to my question is **no**: I will never get the Matlab's syntax `[B,C]=f(A);`. However, I can achieve `result = f(A);` and then use `std::tie (B, C) = result;` or `B = result.B;` and `C = result.C;`. In the first case, I can directly use `std::tie(B, C) = f(A);`. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: But in the `pair(tuple)/tie` case, can I use some trickery to mask the `std::tie (B, C)` syntax to finally have something like `(B,C)=f(A);`? Again, thanks.

Comment: If you return a pair, use tie in the very same statement (like your last code snippet). If you return a custom struct, access it like `result.B` in the next statement.

Comment: Yeah, tie is designed to make it almost look like a "return multiple values" thing, only with the additional "std::tie" before the parentheses. If you add `using std::tie;` (recommended just after the includes) you only have to write `tie(B, C) = f(A)`, which is even more like your requested syntax. I even like the last bit of verbosity in the syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure if tie works with pair. If you have problems, try a 2-element tuple. They might be convertible though.

Comment: I have summarized your solution in my edited post. I have verified that everything works good also with `std::pair` and `std::make_pair` for the particular case of only two outputs. Again, thanks.